# PHP web api error data not fetch for login page

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, api

```
<?php

require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();

// json response array
$response = array("error" => FALSE);

if (isset($_POST['loginid']) && isset($_POST['password'])) 
{

    // receiving the post params
    $loginid = $_POST['loginid'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // get the user by loginid and password
    $user = $db->getUserByEmailAndPassword($loginid, $password);

    if ($user != false) {
        // user is found
        $response["error"] = FALSE;
        $response["No"] = $user["No"];
        $response["user"]["username"] = $user["username"];
        $response["user"]["loginid"] = $user["loginid"];
        $response["user"]["password"] = $user["password"];
        $response["user"]["role"] = $user["role"];
        $response["user"]["designation"] = $user["designation"];
        $response["user"]["status"] = $user["status"];
        //$response["user"]["designation"] = $user["designation"];


        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // user is not found with the credentials
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Login credentials are wrong. Please try again!";

        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required post params is missing
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Required parameters login ID or password is missing!";


    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($response);

    }
?>
```

The above code is login web api for login page but when I run this page that time error comes {"error":true,"error_msg":"Required parameters login ID or password is missing!"} but my password and parameter is correct where I am wrong

Below code is db function.php

```
<?php

class DB_Functions {

    private $conn;

    // constructor
    function __construct() {
        require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
        // connecting to database
        $db = new Db_Connect();
        $this->conn = $db->connect();
    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() {

    }

    /**
     * Storing new user
     * returns user details
     */
    public function storeUser($loginid, $password) {

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO cz(No, status, email, role, loginid, username, designation, password ) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW())");
        $stmt->bind_param("ssssssss", $No, $status, $email, $role, $loginid, $username, $designation, $password );
        $result = $stmt->execute();


        $stmt->close();


        if ($result) {
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM cz WHERE loginid = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $loginid);
            $stmt->execute();
            $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
            $stmt->close();

            return $user;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get user by login id and password
     */
    public function getUserByEmailAndPassword($loginid, $password) {

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM cz WHERE loginid = ?");

        $stmt->bind_param("s", $loginid);

        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
            $stmt->close();

            // verifying user password

            $password = $user['password'];

            // check for password equality
            if ($password == $password) {
                // user authentication details are correct
                return $user;
            }
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check user is existed or not
     */
    public function isUserExisted($loginid) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT loginid from cz WHERE loginid = ?");

        $stmt->bind_param("s", $loginid);

        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->store_result();

        if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
            // user existed 
            $stmt->close();
            return true;
        } else {
            // user not existed
            $stmt->close();
            return false;
        }
    }



}

?>
```

Where i am wrong or any mistake or any idea

Comment: ```if (isset($_POST['loginid']) && isset($_POST['password']))``` is evaluating to __false__. So one of the two fields is missing from the call to the php page.

Comment: For starters you're wanting to insert into 8 fields but have 9 entries.. Here's the clue for the extra value that has nowhere to go `NOW()`

Comment: and.. where are `$No, $status, $email, $role, $loginid, $username, $designation, $password` these all stored within your public function? I see loginid and password only.

Comment: @SloanThrasher that is not the only case that would return the response shown

Comment: @charlieft: it's the only case in the first php code shown that would output the specific text the OP mentions.

Comment: dear I am not inserting any value my function getUserByEmailAndPassword for login page and storeUser function for reg page exctly where I am wrong I am new in web api @Option

Comment: you rewrites the original `$password` in the `getUserByEmailAndPassword`. And what is the `if ($password == $password)`?

Comment: Done Thanks @Deadoonshka